# Element.but selector CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I saw this code on one the sites I am studying.

```
.site-header .widget-area span.but
```

I am still kind of new to the whole CSS thing but what exactly does the **span.but** part mean? Is it the same as the pseudo selector :not?

Comment: It's just a css class.

Comment: It means a `<span>` with a class `but`

Comment: This clears up things for me. I have been tearing my hair out for hours. Thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's just a regular class selector matching the class "but". There are no class selectors that have special meanings like pseudo-classes do. Every class selector is a literal match for class names within the class attribute in HTML, or whatever represents a class name in the document language.

Comment: Thanks for the help now I understand

Answer (score 0):

It is the way of representing two class of same element to increase the weight.

for example

```
<div class="menu nav">
  <div class="sub-menu">
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code `.menu .sub-menu` and `.menu.nav .sub-menu` will represent same element i.e. `.sub-menu` but `.menu.nav .sub-menu` has higher weight than `.menu .sub-menu`.

P.S. Higher weight means the one with high weight will apply first than rest.